# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000018) - Windows 8 x64

Tags: windows, windows-8

Today I started my computer and some errors showed up like this one, so some programs in autorun didn't started:

[image: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000018). Click OK to close the application]

I have this error when opening lot of programs, I can't even use 7zip. The only thing I did yesterday was to install a game through Steam and now I can't use like 70% of the software on my PC (most of them get this error on the entire program and some only on certain modules of it).

I just ran a `SFC /scannnow` and the result was: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations".

Could this be some kind of a virus or Steam that messed up something? What should I do?

Comment: Its not a virus but your registry is still corrupt.  I would use a restoration point to resolve this problem

Comment: Unfortunately I disabled restoration points on my PC to preserve my SSD, so I can't do that

Comment: You can try to de-install the game, by steam you can install it back every time - maybe this helps?

Comment: I could try but I think Steam will just delete some files, and not fix my registry problems.

Comment: This depends on what game it is, is worth a try ;)

Comment: @Daniele - Steam does not modify the registry.  The installation of DirectX might.  You also assume it was the Steam event and no some other event.

Comment: DO you have Malwarebytes ANti-Exploit or EMET installed? This error is thrown when they block a program - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly/cd96802d-7ac7-4e5f-899b-4ce7195900b1?auth=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for all suggestions, after some Googling I found this solution that actually looks like it worked for me:

1. Press Win+R and type `regedit`
2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\­Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Windo­­ws`
3. Than search for `APPINIT_DLLS` and delete everything in it
4. Reboot

Comment: Can you link to the site where you found info about this registry edit? What does it even do?

Comment: Oddly I found this solution in a YouTube video... I don't know why it did messed up or why this solved my problem but it worked.

Comment: I'm having this same problem lately, and found this registry "fix" mentioned several places, but that key is already empty on my system.

Comment: My key was empty as well, and I was getting the error trying to run javaw / java sdk 8. Deleted the empty key, rebooted again, and it worked. Maybe it was the third reboot that did the trick, who knows.

Comment: This doesn't work for Windows 7+ OS, because the APPINIT_DLLS mechanism is disabled by default.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid very few people know the root cause of the mysterious 0xC0000018 EXE launch error because Microsoft makes it vague, even until Windows 10. When reading Jeffrey Richter's *Programming Applications for MS Windows* 4th-ed, I happened to find it out.

**If a DLL requires to be loaded at a fixed address(in process virtual address space), but the requirement cannot be fulfilled, Windows asserts the very 0xC0000018 error.** But there is no apparent clue to tell which DLL(s) cause the problem. A simple Google search of "0xC0000018" just pops you with lots of posts of baffled users.

To reproduce, you can prepare a solution(Visual Studio term) with one EXE and two DLL, and set both DLL to have linker option `/FIXED /BASE:"0x44440000"` and have the EXE implicitly load the two DLLs, then you will see 0xC0000018 error on EXE launch.

And yes, clearing out `APPINIT_DLLS` in the registry is your first bet to get rid of the possible culprits. Those DLLs (possibly from malware/spyware) will be loaded into every process you launch so may ruin your live.

I think Microsoft designed this DLL-force-loading facility for developing/debugging purposes, so for normal users, that `APPINIT_DLLS` should remain empty.

Then how to pinpoint the actual culprit DLL? Perhaps there is a way, use dumpbin.exe to check every DLL in `APPINIT_DLLS` or other possible auto-loaded DLLs(help with [AutoRuns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)), check them one by one with `dumpbin -headers`. If there is no `.reloc` section, it is a *fixed-location* DLL.

Comment: A faster way is to use `procmon`. The last DLL the process was trying to load must be the one which triggered the error.

Comment: A non-obvious way to trigger this error is when the executable has a very large data section (e.g. static arrays). If the section is large enough that it encroaches on some kernel dll's fixed address, `c0000018` will occur if the executable is 32-bit. With 64-bit executables, Windows refuses to load them with 'bad image' error, which is quite confusing. Note that the error can appear and disappear with debug/release builds and appear unexpectedly after Windows updates change the address space layout of system dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed about 40 games through Steam and don't have any problems, no, I don't think its a bad of Steam. Try to restore your system using Windows Restore Points: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows-vista/system-restore-frequently-asked-questions

[EDITED] Maybe some DLL are missed, you can test the dependencies of the program you can't start using Dependency Walker: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Like I said in the comment above I disabled restoration points on my PC to preserve my SSD, so I can't do that. I can't even serach for `Restore` in my PC because when I press the Windows button and I try to search something in the "Settings" tab then Metro just freeze.

Comment: Well, like I said above (if you like it this way), You can try to de-install the game, by steam you can install it back every time - maybe this helps?

Comment: @Daniele - If your unable to even view the Start Screen its time to `Refresh` your `Windows 8` installation.  This will require the reinstallation of your desktop applications.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is  associated with the following MS Update and McAfee Data Loss Prevention Endpoint (DLP Endpoint). It seems that there is a conflict between MS update and McAfee Data Loss Prevention Endpoint.

Visit the following websites please:
[Microsoft Patch MS15-038 on Windows 7 when Data Loss Prevention Endpoint is installed](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=kb84538)
[Microsoft Security Bulletin MS15-038 - Important](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms15-038.aspx)

Comment: It will also affect explorer.exe and cmd. After windows start up, explorer associated programs will prompt: "Server Execution Failed".

Comment: Maybe, but the OP did not mentions using McAfee and his post is 2 years old. He fixed his problem without your patch and your patch is a very recent one. In any case, please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.